# ios switching views not functional

Tags: ios, navigation, back

I tried a simple app, switching one view to another.
but i met a problem, it show error of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS THREAD 1`,

I used zombie to check the error, it shows the error from the first switch method ,not the back method ,here is the switch method, i am not able to find the error.

```
- (IBAction)YukiBanButtonPress:(id)sender {
    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] endEditing:YES];
    AboutUs*AboutusController= [[[AboutUs alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutUs" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    [AboutusController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
    [self.view addSubview:AboutusController.view];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:AboutusController animated:YES];
    [AboutusController.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [AboutusController setYukiBan];
    [AboutusController.navigationItem setTitle:@"YUKI BAN"];
}
```

here is the backbutton program

```
UINavigationItem*item= [NavigationBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UINavigationItem *back = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"];
    NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:back,item,nil];
    [NavigationBar setItems:items];
    [back release];
    [items release];
    [NavigationBar setDelegate:self];
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: should be clear. When you get crash? while creating button or tappin on button? in Which button? where did you wire up this method `YukiBanButtonPress:`?

Comment: Why are you calling `release` on those objects? You're not using ARC?

Comment: where is this back button? in Aboutus Controller

Comment: i got the crash when i press back button back to menview ， the back button is in another view ,the second view , when call the method YukiBanButtonPress it switch to the second view .

Comment: I fixed this problem ,sorry to disturb ,it's about the app delegate problem, the first view i didn't use it as a navigation controller, so it can not do navigation functions. thanks all of your